# Django Channels and Web Socket with 3rd party database

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, django-models, websocket, django-channels

I want to create one Dashboard to show users count for my ML project where I'm updating users count in MongoDB on friction of seconds. I need to show that count in dashboard with real time sockets.

I'm familiar with Django and little bit knowledge about Django Channels, but when I update my mongo database with simple python script which is running in ML machine and updating count to db, how can django or channels know that I need to send that data in Dashboard?

Should I need to use Django Models in this case or not!
What if I'm updating through Python Mongo Script? 
Please help me to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

For channels the message handling methods in channels to be triggered you need to publish a message to the channel group that the consumer is subscribe to. So you would need to import channels in your `Python Mongo Script` and there publish to the group see: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers

you will also need a channels layer set up, Redis or rabbitMQ are the common solutions for this.